LoadBalancer: add http header before send request to backend
I need a component, probably a Load Balancer or a proxy, that adds a custom header on my http hequest before sending it to the backend (spring app running on a AWS EKS cluster). The value of the header should always be A or B. The rule to add A or B in the header should be configurable ate runtime,   as if I had a file with the content:
A: 30%
B: 70%
So 30% of requests should have x-my-custom-header: A and 70% of the requests having  x-my-custom-header: B . I need to be able to change it at runtime without restarting the PODs in my cluster. Any suggestions?

You can consider using Envoy for you specification - HTTP header manipulation.
For the the A|B weighting, you may configure a ConfigMap.
